# The three messengers and Abraham

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, malach-angel, abraham, genesis-bereishith

Talmud and Midrash give their explanation of the three angels that Abraham (be peace upon him) met in chapter 18 of Genesis. They both offer the same names for the angels: Michael, Gabriel and Raphael. But it seems to me that they contradict each other in explaining who does what.
According to the Talmud ([Bava Metzia 86b:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.86b.20?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)): Michael announces to Sarah the birth of Isaac, Raphael heals Abraham and Gabriel destroys Sodom. When Gabriel goes to Sodom **Michael goes with him to save Lot**.
According to the Midrash ([Bereshit Rabbah 50:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.50.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) Michael departs and **Raphael goes to Sodom with Gabriel to save Lot**.

So, who goes to Sodom? Michael or Raphael?

Comment: I don't know the answer but it's very interesting. Speculation: Gabriel is Hashem's messenger of justice, Raphael is His messenger of mercy. Was it an act of justice or mercy to save Lot? Maybe this is the heart of the debate here

Comment: Note that according to Tosafot, the Talmud is compatible with the Midrash's assertion that angels can only do one mission, and the Midrash is compatible with the Talmud's assertion that Raphael healed Avraham. He seems to content to leave the issue of who saved Lot in dispute.

Comment: See, however, [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.50.11?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Bereshit_Rabbah.50.11.3&lang2=bi) to Bereshit Rabbah 50:11, who seems to suggest that Michael and Raphael both went to save Lot. I don't know how to reconcile that with Michael's departure in 50:2 and the rule that angels don't share missions.

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii I think it's both. Because the words of Abraham to G-d about the destruction of Sodom raise a dilemma about justice, how can HaShem who is just kill the sinner and the righteous together? But it's also an act of kindness and mercy, I think, because unfortunately the righteous isn't always rewarded in this world, but Lot was.